# Controlling a 24V solenoid with a 5V signal

Tags: arduino, control, solenoid

I have a 24V drawstop solenoid that is for pipe organs to push and pull the organ registers, allowing for airflow through different pipes. The solenoid has two active low control pins, one for pulling the register out and one for pushing it in.

I would like to control the solenoid with a 5V control signal from an Arduino. So far I've been using a MOSFET as a switch in a simple setup like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnvuOX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which seems to work fine. My problem is that I have about 20 of these solenoids and each of them would need two MOSFETs (one for push and one for pull), so 40 MOSFETs in total. I was wondering if there is a smarter and less space consuming way of doing this?

I recently stumbled upon the tri-state logic buffer, which seems like it could do the same job, but with multiple buffers in a small IC. However I'm not sure they are meant for switching a larger voltage. The ones I've seen use the same voltage for in- and output.

When on the solenoid draws 0.35 amps. It will only be on for about 50ms at a time.

I'm a bit of a newbie so any input is appreciated.

Comment: `I was wondering if there is a smarter and less space consuming way of doing this?` - an electronic organ would be a whole lot smaller all round. Just saying. How are the drawstops currently driven?

Comment: Do you know what the current draw of the solenoids is? Also, what is the duty cycle (how long do they remain energized at a time?

Comment: Currently they are operated by hand. An electric organ might be smarter in some ways, but in this case the question is more about the electronics than the organ.    The solenoids draw up to 0.3 amps. They don't have to be on for more than about 100 ms

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit is good as you know. To make it smaller there are a plethora of solenoid drivers on the market. Since I do not know your skill set or resources available I will suggest non SMD parts although they are available that way as well. The ULN2007, ULN2803 and others should do exactly what you want. The ULN2007 has 7 drivers in it and the ULN2008 has eight. These can be purchased in a variety of packages, dip  as well as SMD. These are also available on modules for the Arduino. There are other modules available as well.

Comment: The ULN-type drivers will likely work for this. Be sure to use the COM pin to clamp the inductive voltage spikes when the driver turns off. If you don't care about the spec of turn-off, connecting COM to the +24V supply would work.

Comment: Downvoting, I'm afraid. This recommends replacing practically zero-loss MOSFETs with ancient and inefficient ULN2x Darlington parts that drop power and produce heat. The recommendation has normally been the other way around for decades. I was designing ULN2003s out in the 1990s and there are much better multi-FET ICs on the market these days (I won't say which, part recc'ds off-topic).

Comment: Granted that the old ULN devices aren’t a modern choice but they are cheap and ubiquitous. A common solution would  be a string of 74HC595 and ULN2803 or a more integrated solution like the tpic6b595.

Comment: @Kartman, it's not some 'old age chip' rejection though, tons (eg 74HCTxx) are 30+yo and great. I think ULN2x come up a lot on this site - but so do very-superseded 741 and 555 :-) MOSFET packs rarely do. I think ULN2x get recc'd as they're easy 'knowns'. It's different in industry. I looked closely at ULN2003s for mass-production in 1990s, since haven't seen them in any client's design in the last 30 years (nor using 595's, which often comes up here but I couldn't call 'common'). The answer advises the OP *away* from MOSFETs to these worse parts, which is the bit I had an opinion and vote on.

Comment: @TonyM would you recommend sticking with the MOSFET setup instead? Do you know of any multi-fet ICs that would fit the purpose?

Comment: @Fet. You got a multi-fet recommendation! You've still not given us a current value yet and for your mosfet circuit you'd want a flyback diode across the solenoid or some other clamp method. TonyM- when I say 'common' - it's in the context of Arduino land. Last time I designed in a ULN2803 was back in the 90's along with an 8051. Not something you'd see me do today

Comment: @Kartman I've added the current to the original description. The solenoid draws 0.35 amps when on and only has to stay on for about 50ms at a time.